# How to set the Tabview in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to make an Android app in which I want to use a `Tabview` to navigate among the screens. When I am putting it at the bottom or at the top of the screen, it works fine. But according to the app requirements, I want to put it in the middle of the screen. i.e. in between the elements of the `FrameLayout`. Here is the code for two basic situations:

(1) **to put the `Tabview` at bottom:**

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TabWidget 
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

(2) **to put the `Tabview` at the Top:**

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

<TabWidget 
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />  

<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

(3)  **What I want to do:**

I want to put the `Tabview` in between the elements of the `FrameLayout`. To be more specific:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/now_lisn_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/background">

<include android:id="@+id/main_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/back_header" />

<include android:id="@+id/image_name_strip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/image_name_holder"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

<ListView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@color/listDivider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    style="@style/listBackground" 
    android:id="@+id/list"/>           
</LinearLayout>
```

The above layout contains the elements of the `FrameLayout`. I want to put the `Tabview` just above the `ListView`. Is there any way to do it?